# Font family select is not applying at the same time, its getting updated when I select next font family

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, knockoutjs

this is my select option in html

```
<div class="control">
                    <select id="selected_font_id" data-bind="value: getObservable('selected_font'),
                            event:{ change: changeMessageFontStyle}">
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please select the font</option>
                        <option value="Freestyle Script">Freestyle Script</option>
                        <option value="Arriel">Ariel</option>
                        <option value="Calibri">Calibri</option>
                        <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                        <option value="French Script MT">French Script MT</option>
                        <option value="Lucida Handwriting">Lucida Handwriting</option>
                        <option value="Sylfaen">Sylfaen</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
```

this is my preview to show the font change

```
<div  class="gift-message-preview" data-bind="visible: formPreviewVisibility() || resultBlockVisibility() ">
    
    <p><span data-bind="i18n: 'To'">To:</span>
        <!-- ko text: getObservable('recipient') --><!-- /ko -->
        <br>
        <span id="test" data-bind="i18n: 'Message:'">Message:</span>
        
        <!-- ko text: getObservable('message') --><!-- /ko -->
        <br>
        <span>From:</span><!-- ko text: getObservable('sender') --><!-- /ko -->
    </p>
   
</div>
```

this is my JS with JQuery

```
changeMessageFontStyle: function () { 
            this.model.getObservable('selected_font').subscribe(function (value) {
                //alert(value);
                //alert('changeMessageFontStyle');
                $("#selected_font_id").change(function () {
                    //alert($(this).val());
                    $('.gift-message-preview').css("font-family", value);

                });
                
            });
        },
```

**can anyone help?**

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added more complexity to this than is needed.

The simplest way to achieve this will be to use the [style binding.](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html)

Something like this should do the job:

```
<div data-bind="style: {'font-family': selected_font }">
```

This will automatically update the font family whenever the selected_font observable changes.

Using jQuery within Knockout isn't advisable as it's easy to run into conflicts/problems like you have here.

Comment: this also working, but the same issue is there, its not changing on first select, its getting change from second select onward